# How to download a Excel file from behind a paywall into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have this website that requires log in to access data.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get(my_url, cookies=my_cookies) # my_cookies are imported from a selenium session.
df = pd.io.excel.read_excel(r.content, sheetname=0)
```

Reponse:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Ticker\tAction\tName\tShares\tPrice\...
```

Apparently, the str is processed as a file**name**. Is there a way to process it as a file? Alternatively can we pass cookies to pd.get_html?

EDIT: After further processing we can now see that this is actually a csv file. The content of the downloaded file is:

```
In [201]: r.content
Out [201]: 'Ticker\tAction\tName\tShares\tPrice\tCommission\tAmount\tTarget Weight\nBRSS\tSELL\tGlobal Brass and Copper Holdings Inc\t400.0\t17.85\t-1.00\t7,140\t0.00\nCOHU\tSELL\tCohu Inc\t700.0\t12.79\t-1.00\t8,953\t0.00\nUNTD\tBUY\tUnited Online Inc\t560.0\t15.15\t-1.00\t-8,484\t0.00\nFLXS\tBUY\tFlexsteel Industries Inc\t210.0\t40.31\t-1.00\t-8,465\t0.00\nUPRO\tCOVER\tProShares UltraPro S&P500\t17.0\t71.02\t-0.00\t-1,207\t0.00\n'
```

Notice that it is tab delimited. Still, trying:

```
# csv version 1
df = pd.read_csv(r.content) 
# Returns error, file does not exist. Apparently read_csv() is also trying to read it as a file.

# csv version 2
fh = io.BytesIO(r.content)
df = pd.read_csv(fh) # ValueError: No columns to parse from file.

# csv version 3
s = StringIO(r.content)
df = pd.read_csv(s)
# No error, but the resulting df is not parsed properly; \t's show up in the text of the dataframe.
```

Comment: Do you pay for the site?  Not good form to ask how to violate Terms of Service.

Comment: Yes I pay for it and the TOS allow it.

Comment: I got it now. These StringIO()s are tricky. They self destruct after the first use. Both version 2 and version 3 work when adding a second parameter to specify the delimiter; but only the first time that they are read. `df = pd.read_csv(fh, '\t')` works!

Comment: They don't self-destruct, they behave like any file- when you read you move cursor. When you read again you read starting from where cursor is located. To be able to read the file again you want to use seek method: s.seek(0)
Keep that in mind, you might need this in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply wrap the file contents in a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html%23io.BytesIO):

```
with io.BytesIO(r.content) as fh:
    df = pd.io.excel.read_excel(fh, sheetname=0)
```

Comment: That did the trick, but unfortunately it hit another snag. `df = pd.io.excel.read_excel(fh)` gives the message `Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found 'Ticker\tA'`. Apparently the 'Excel' file is really a csv file. (See my edited question). Trying `df = pd.read_csv(fh)` gives the error `ValueError: No columns to parse from file`

Comment: Got it! `pd.read_csv()` just needed a second parameter to specify that the delimiter is '\t'.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was included in an [update](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7531) from 2014. According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) it is as simple as providing the url:

> The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local file could be file://localhost/path/to/workbook.xlsx

Based on the code you've provided, it looks like you are using pandas 0.13.x? If you can upgrade to a newer version (code below is tested with 0.16.x) you can get this to work without the additional utilization of the `requests` library. This was added in 0.14.1

```
data2 = pd.read_excel(data_url)
```

As an example of a full script (with the example XLS document taken from the [original bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6809) report stating the `read_excel` didn't accept a URL):

```
import pandas as pd
data_url = "http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/xls/PET_PRI_ALLMG_A_EPM0_PTC_DPGAL_M.xls"
data = pd.read_excel(data_url, "Data 1", skiprows=2)
```

Comment: This answer only works when there is no need to log in.