# Python: How to read excel file from Requests response?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, xlrd

I am downloading an excel file as a stream using the requests library.

`r = requests.get(my_url, stream=True)`

I want to read the data in this excel file, for that I can am trying to use pandas. But I am not sure how to read the file from the response I get. What can I do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a url in pandas directly to read the excel file without using requests.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(my_url)
```

If it is necessary to retreive the data via requests, then this answer from here ([How to download a Excel file from behind a paywall into a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961190/how-to-download-a-excel-file-from-behind-a-paywall-into-a-pandas-dataframe)) may suffice:

> Simply wrap the file contents in a BytesIO:
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd
> import io
>
> with io.BytesIO(r.content) as fh:
>     df = pd.io.excel.read_excel(fh, sheet_name=0) #sheetname becomes sheet_name
> ```