# Problem in reading Excel file form url into a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, python-requests

How can I read excel file from a url into a dataframe?

```
import requests
request_url = 'https://pishtazfund.com/Download/DownloadNavChartList?exportType=Excel&fromDate=5/9/2008&toDate=2/22/2022&basketId=0'
response = requests.get(request_url, headers={'Accept': 'text/html'})
```

I can not convert the response into a dataframe, any idea or solution appreciated

Comment: Does this [Python: How to read excel file from Requests response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147689/python-how-to-read-excel-file-from-requests-response) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use panda's `read_csv()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://pishtazfund.com/Download/DownloadNavChartList?exportType=Excel&fromDate=5/9/2008&toDate=2/22/2022&basketId=0')
```

Comment: This technique does not work for the given url, furthermore, I have to use "request"